# How to compare the values from a column in csv file according to key values that are duplicated using python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a .csv file with 2 columns :

```
Item   Value
A   1.3
B   2.6
D   4.2
E   5.6
F   3.2
A   1.2
C   5.2
D   6.4
```

I want to compare the values in column Item and find the duplicates, after that I want to compare the corresponding values from column Value. 
In the example A and D from Item are duplicated, but they have different values in Value. I would like to clear the duplicates and save the ones with the lowest value in Value.

That's what I've tried and it works, but it is SLOW and resource expensive. I am sure there is a better way, I could use pandas or any other library for that matter, so please give me a suggestion.

```
file="file.csv"

def items_array(file):


    with open(file,"r") as file:
        file_reader=csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=";")
        for row in file_reader:
            items.append(row["Item_title"])
    items_set=set(items)
    return(items_set)


def find_lowest_value(item,file):

    items_and_values=[]

    with open(file,"r") as file:
        file_reader=csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=";")
        for row in file_reader:
            items_and_values.append([row["Item"],row["Value"]])


    value_for_single_item=[]

    for i in items_and_values:

        if item == i[0]:

            value_for_single_item.append(i[1])


    value_for_single_item.sort()

    return(value_for_single_item[0])


items=items_array(file)

for i in items:
    lv=find_lowest_value(i,file)
    print(i,lv)
```

Since the rows in the actual .csv file are about 25k with the method I am using it takes about 30 minutes. I am sure it could be done faster and smarter :)

This is the expected result :

```
Item    Value
B   2.6
D   4.2
E   5.6
F   3.2
A   1.2
C   5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import your csv in a Dataframe using Pandas, you don't have to read the file 25k, just once. And it'll be a lot quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.read_csv(file,sep=";")

a=df.groupby("Item")["Value"].min()
```

Pretty much does the trick. Two lines of code and it took 2 seconds to do it. Pandas has to be some kind of magic.